# PHP stdClass Object array looping

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

I am trying to figure out how i can loop through this stdClass Object. I am trying to get the **path** value of each **contents array item [0]-[?]**.

The Object array looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
   [hash] => zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
   [revision] => 22
   [rev] => 161f5f4043
   [thumb_exists] => 
   [bytes] => 0
   [modified] => Sun, 23 Mar 2014 18:05:38 +0000
   [path] => /Camera Uploads
   [is_dir] => 1
   [icon] => folder_photos
   [root] => dropbox
   [contents] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [revision] => 47
                [rev] => 2f1f5f4043
                [thumb_exists] => 1
                [bytes] => 3212196
                [modified] => Sun, 23 Mar 2014 18:07:05 +0000
                [client_mtime] => Wed, 05 Feb 2014 19:10:14 +0000
                [path] => /Camera Uploads/2014-02-05 14.10.13.jpg
                [is_dir] => 
                [icon] => page_white_picture
                [root] => dropbox
                [mime_type] => image/jpeg
                [size] => 3.1 MB
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                etc etc...
```

Currently i am trying the following code to loop:

```
line 75: print_r ($dropbox->GetMetadata($file->path));

line 77: foreach ($dropbox->GetMetadata($file->path) as $arr) {
line 78:    foreach ($arr as $obj) {
line 79:        $path   = $obj->path;
line 80:        echo $path;
line 81:    }
line 82: }
```

But i keep getting this error:

```
( ! ) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
                C:\wamp\www\test\sample.php on line 78 

Call Stack 

#   Time       Memory      Function        Location 
1   0.0011     157592      {main}(  )      ..\sample.php:0
```

Comment: Just remove the inner foreach loop, `var_dump($arr);` and you'll see. Btw, `$arr` is a misleading variable name. It should be `$property` as you are iterating over an object's properties

Comment: @hek2mgl then i get an error of **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\test\sample.php on line 78**

Comment: Think about it again, try it again and you'll see. Once you are enlightened you'll see that there is not much to say

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
foreach($dropbox->GetMetadata($file->path) as $result){ //Process each value as $result
if(is_array($result)){       //If $result is an array continue ('contents')
foreach($result as $value){  //Process each value from $result (0..x)
echo"{$value->path}\n";    //Echo what you are looking for ('contents'>'0'>'path')
}}}
```

Comment: OK, the `echo` wasn't treating `$value` as an object. Try now?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) wants to receive an array or an object, as stated by

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
>                   C:\wamp\www\test\sample.php on line 78

when doing the foreach on line 77 you give it a whole dropbox object. then, on line 78, you do a foreach on that general object properties, **but the first key of the general object (`hash`) is not an array**, giving you your error. just give the right content to the first foreach:

```
$object = $dropbox->GetMetadata($file->path);
foreach ($object->contents as $arr) {
  foreach ($arr as $obj) {
    $path = $obj->path;
    echo $path;
  }
}
```